# Using MVC3/Razor where would I put images that were specific to one view?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3

Using MVC3/Razor where would I put images that were specific to one view?

[image: A graphical display of the text following] I had thought to put it in the /views/home folder and then reference it with the following line inside `/views/home/index.cshtml`, but I'm not getting it to resolve.

```
<a href="@Url.Content("rawchart.PNG")" target="_blank" style="float:right;"><img src="@Url.Content("rawchart.PNG")" style="max-width: 128px; max-height: 64px;" title="click to view in a new window or tab" /></a>
```

(so that you see my intent)

Is this a dumb way of doing this? Should I just have it in `/content/images` instead?

Comment: Yes! `/content/images` is the best place to have images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could place them in:

```
~/Content/images/Home/Index/image1.png
~/Content/images/Home/Index/image2.png
~/Content/images/Home/Edit/image1.png
~/Content/images/Home/Edit/image2.png
...
```

and then:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Foo")" target="_blank" style="float:right;">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/home/index/image1.png")" style="max-width: 128px; max-height: 64px;" title="click to view in a new window or tab" />
</a>
```

Comment: That's what I figured I was gonna have to do ... That's why I wanted to simply screenshot what I was doing, I figured it captured the essence fast enough to get an easy answer out. Dangit. Someone should figure out a way to make this magic work too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put them in the Views folder. No content can be there. There really isn't an 'mvc way'. Just use something like /content/images/viewname.

Answer (score 1):

Put the images in your Content folder (or subfolder) and use a relative URL

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/myimage.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably put the images with the other images in the Content folder. I would lay out your images folder (in Content) similarly to your Views folder if it makes it easier for your and future maintainers to manage. I do something similar with javascript in the Scripts folder.